# What type of creative commons licensing do I need for free templates?

Tags: licensing

I'm planning on releasing a design template for a specific platform to make it easier on users who use that platform to design their pages. I want to allow anyone to download this template for free; however, I would not like anybody to sell this template or use it as artwork in a project. Basically, I just want to allow people to use it to build their designs. Do I need CC licensing and if so, what type of CC licensing do I need?

Answer (score 1):

Use the GNU GPL. It's not creative commons, but it essentially says that anyone can use it, so long as they also license it under the GPL and don't sell it.

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

It's intended more for software releases, but because what you're doing is akin to a software release and what the GPL is intended for, I think it would work better than a Creative Commons license.

Comment: As far as I know the GPL *does* allow anyone to redistribute content both commercially and non-commercially.

Comment: You're wrong, and @LeaHayes is right. The GPL does *not* say that people can't sell stuff. In fact, precisely the opposite. (It does tend to make it unlikely in practise, mind you.)

Comment: @TRiG you felt the need to make that comment. Two and a half years later?

Comment: I don't see what dates have to do with anything.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you need this

Attribution-NonCommercial

This license lets others remix, tweak, and build upon your work non-commercially, and although their new works must also acknowledge you and be non-commercial, they don’t have to license their derivative works on the same terms.

For more detail Please see this...

- [Make sure you understand how Creative Commons licenses operate](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Before_Licensing)
- [types of licenses YOU need](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/)